# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error running RNetLogo on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 - but is the issue rJava or NetLogo?

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, netlogo, rjava

**The issue**

I am attempting to start an instance of NetLogo in R using the RNetLogo package, which has rJava as a dependency.

During installation of rJava 0.9-9 (the latest development snapshot from rforge), I get the following errors:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

This appears to refer to Java version 6, even though I have version 8 only on my machine. However, the developer of rJava appears to say [here](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/123) that as long as the package installs and loads correctly, which it does, then users should ignore the warnings. Furthermore, .jinit() appears to run correctly:

```
> .jinit()
[1] 0
```

and the correct version of Java is detected:

```
> .jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
[1] "1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12"
```

So, having loaded RNetLogo, I attempt to start a NetLogo instance. Here is the minimal code I'm running:

```
library(RNetLogo)
nl.path <- "~/NetLogo 6.0.2/app"
NLStart(nl.path, gui = FALSE,  nl.jarname='netlogo-6.0.2.jar')
```

Which returns the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nlogo/workspace/Controllable
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I get the same issue using RStudio or running R from the terminal (including running as root).

My full sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8          LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8      LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RNetLogo_1.0-4 igraph_1.1.2   rJava_0.9-9   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.4.3     pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

**Attempted fixes**

Based on other users' issues that appear to be related, I also tried to following:

° Setting environment variables in /etc/profile.d/:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server"
export CLASSPATH="$ClASSPATH:$HOME/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/java"
```

° Running
    sudo R CMD javareconf -e

° Adding a couple of lines proposed as mac OS fixes to the start of my script:

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=1)
dyn.load('/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so')
```

**Thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time staring at this question, assuming I had the same issue because I was getting the same error. So, for future readers: On Ubuntu 17.10, with rJava 0.9-9, NetLogo 6.0.3 and RNetLogo 1.0-4, the same error results when using the Oracle 9 Java SDK. Going back to 8 solves it.

For the OP: The ~/ in nl.path might be the problem. On my system it doesn't work, but specifying the full path (that is, home/user_name/...) does.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with rNetLogo 1.0-4 for NetLogo 5.3.1 in combination with openjdk-8 on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried openjdk-8 and Oracle Java 8 (using ppa:webupd8team/java) with no luck.

In the end it works with rJava as Ubuntu package (r-cran-rjava) and going back to rNetLogo 1.0-0 (with I suppose did the trick), still using Oracle Java 8.

```
url = 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RNetLogo/RNetLogo_1.0-0.tar.gz'
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="source")
```